# Mongoose TypeError on a model's findOne method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

The following TypeError cropped up in some old code.

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'findOne'
```

The Model that was affected recently had two new static methods defined and those methods referenced external models. After backing out the new static methods, I was able to determine the root cause to be the require statements of the external models. The pattern looks like the following:

```
var UserModel = require('./user');

var GroupSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    users: [{ type : Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'UserModel'}],
});

GroupSchema.statics.findSomeUsers = function(group, callback) {
    this.find({name : session_user._id}, function(err, groups) {
        UserModel.find({_id : {$in : group.users}}, function(err,patients) {
            // do magic
        });
    });
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('GroupModel', GroupSchema);
```

There is a code fragment in the application that calls GroupModel.findOne({name:'gogo'}) that leads to the TypeError. when I remove the require statement for the UserModel in the GroupSchema, app code works again.

Why does Javascript start to think findOne() is an instance method with the addition of the require statement?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's known node.js issue. It means that you have looping require somewhere in your code and node.js forbids it.

The right way to do it is by using `mongoose.model` method. So, instead of `UserModel` variable you shall use `mongoose.model('UserModel')`. So, when `findSomeUsers` will be called mondoose will fetch `UserModel` and invoke its `find` method.

```
GroupSchema.statics.findSomeUsers = function(group, callback) {
    this.find({name : session_user._id}, function(err, groups) {
        mongoose.model('UserModel').find({_id : {$in : group.users}}, function(err,patients) {
            // do magic
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: ./user.js is where the UserModel is defined. There is no require there. I'm not understanding your answer - var UserModel = mongoose.model('UserModel') - fails because it doesn't know what the Schema is (which is defined in user.js).

Comment: remove the require, and change UserModel.findOne() to mongoose.model('UserModel').findOne()

Comment: Have you defined `UserModel` in `'./user'`? Smth like `module.exports = mongoose.model('UserModel', UserSchema);`? If you have, then `mongoose.model('UserModel')` should work fine. As for looping requires, I'm not shure that its your case, but it looks like.

Comment: yes, I've defined UserModel in ./user. I don't see the loop, but replacing the UserModel reference in the static method, the GroupModel works correctly again. That was a bugger - thanks!

Comment: Never would have guessed this. Thanks! Anybody know why Node doesn't log a warning or something when this happens?

Comment: I thought this was a really good way to prevent a circular reference between 2 schemas (where both have calls to each other in their static methods), BUT - it just lurched me onto another error message - MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "MyShareName" - so I'm back to square one unless anyone knows how to solve that too ?!