# Mongoose: calling static method of another schema returns "TypeError: Object has no method 'xxx' "

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my node project, I have defined a dog schema and a cat schema.

The schema are the same(name/age).

Both schema have a static method *sayHello*. The cat schame has an instance method let_dog_speak which will trigger the *sayHello* of the Dog schema, so does the let_cat_speak.

In my route handler, when I am trying to get a dog instance(/getdog/:name), the cat's *sayHello* method will be triggered, vice versa.

The problem is my cat is able to let the dog speak while the dog cannot. I attached below my code and the error messages.

**./model/cat.js**

```
var Dog = require('./dog');

var Cat = new Schema({
    name: { type:String, required:true, trim:true },
    age: { type:Number, required:true, trim:true }
});

Cat.statics.sayHello = function() {
    console.log("Meow meow");
};

Cat.methods.let_dog_speak = function() {
    Dog.sayHello();
};

var cat_model = testdb.model('cat_collection', Cat);
module.exports = cat_model;
```

**./model/dog.js**

```
var Cat = require('./cat');

var Dog = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    age: { type: Number, required:true, trim:true },
});

Dog.statics.sayHello = function() {
    console.log("Wow wow");
};

Dog.methods.let_cat_speak = function() {
    Cat.sayHello();
};

var dog_model = testdb.model('dog_collection', Dog);
module.exports = dog_model;
```

Here is my route, **./route.js**

```
app.get('/getdog/:name', function(req, res) {
    Dog.findOne({
        name: req.params.name
    }, function(error, dog) {
        dog.let_cat_speak(); //This throws error
        res.json(dog);
    });
});

app.get('/getcat/:name', function(req, res) {
    Cat.findOne({
        name: req.params.name,
    }, function(error, cat) {
        cat.let_dog_speak(); //This works, will print wow wow 
        res.json(cat);
    });
});
```

**Error message:**

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'sayHello'
    at model.Dog.methods.let_cat_speak (/home/sliter/Development/nodeJS/mongotest/backend/model/dog.js:16:9)
```

Comment: It may be because of the circulation reference between cat.js and dog.js. Put them in the same file and try.

Comment: Thanks to @sza, the problem is solved by integrating the two files. Besides, I also found this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307953/mongoose-typeerror-on-a-models-findone-method which explains the cause of the problem. In brief, it is nodejs that forbids reference looping. To stay with two files, replacing the require('./dog|cat') statement with mongoose.model('dog|cat_collection') will make the code works.

Comment: You are welcome and I am glad you got your problem solved.