# Mongoose.statics: 'findOne is not a function' + 'create is not a function', confusion over different call types

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a shopping cart model that needs a method to retrieve or create the current users cart.

I was moving a working version from controller to model.statics and ran into some confusion about how to call the **findOne** and **create** methods of the model from within the static function.

I found answers to my problems in these two posts [mongooge-model-findone-typeerror-object-has-no-method-findone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995954/mongooge-model-findone-typeerror-object-has-no-method-findone) and [mongoose-typeerror-on-a-models-findone-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307953/mongoose-typeerror-on-a-models-findone-method)

Essentially my original call to

```
CartSchema.findOne({ userId: userId }, function (err, cart)
```

was fixed by changing to

```
this.findOne({ userId: userId }, function (err, cart)
```

but the same technique did NOT work for the create function, instead my original call to

```
CartSchema.create(cart, function (err, newCart)
```

was fixed using a different style

```
mongoose.model('Cart').create(cart, function (err, newCart)
```

Here is the working code plus comments for what was in place and the exceptions that were thrown

```
CartSchema.statics.getMyCart = function (userId, callback) {
  try {

    // CartSchema.findOne({ userId: userId }, function (err, cart)
    // will throw
    //    TypeError: CartSchema.findOne is not a function
    //
    // this.findOne({ userId: userId }, function (err, cart)
    //    OK

    this.findOne({ userId: userId }, function (err, cart) {

      if (err) {
        return callback(err, null, false);
      }

      if (cart) {
        // If cart exists for this user, then execute callback for additional actions against this cart
        return callback(null, cart, false);
      }

      cart = {
        userId: userId,
        items: []
      };


      // CartSchema.create(cart, function (err, newCart) {
      // will throw
      //    TypeError: CartSchema.create is not a function
      //
      // this.create(cart, function (err, newCart) {
      // will throw 
      //    TypeError: this.create is not a function

      mongoose.model('Cart').create(cart, function (err, newCart) {

        if (err) {
          return callback(err, null, false);
        }

        // Cart has been created for this user, now execute callback for additional actions against this cart
        return callback(null, newCart, true);
      });

    });
  } catch (e) {
    l.exception(e);
  }
}
```